# Can a firefox extension enable/disable other extensions working?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox3.6

I am working with firefox extensions. I want an option of enabling other extension in the options dialog box. this will depend on users choice.
Like for doing some work there are 3 extensions user has. I would like my extension to have an option of asking user which extension outta the three he wants to enable.
I guess all my extension would need to know is the preference settings of others.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: @neil so u think that is possible???

Comment: An extension can do almost anything a user can do, however I don't have specific enough information as to what you want done to suggest how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following links.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Toolkit_API/FUEL
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Toolkit_API/extIExtensions
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Toolkit_API/extIExtension

Comment: Note that the APIs relating to addon management changed between Firefox 3.6 and Firefox 4, so if you want to remain compatible with both versions, you'll need to write some of your code in two different ways.